# Error message of Next without For being recieved

Tags: excel, vba

I've written a macro from parent file to change a child file.

The parent file has 10 + rows I want to cycle through.
The child file looks at row1 and creates a file based on the name in row 1.

I am then using a For and Next function to get the child to look at the next row and save the file based on the new name etc etc.

I get an error of:

> Next without For

My code:

```
Sub CreateModels()

' set parameters
Dim vDestPath As String
Dim vDestFile As String
Dim vSrcePath As String
Dim vCurrFile As String
Dim vSrceFile As String
Dim vTot As Integer

vSrceFile = "Bridge 3-S Financial Model.xlsx"
vSrcePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\Bridge 3-S Financial Model.xlsx"
vCurrFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
vDestPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Output Models\"

'OpenFinancialModel
Workbooks.Open vSrcePath, UpdateLinks:=False
Sheets("Input Sheet Data").Select
Range("A4").Select

'creating models

For vTot = 6 To 1000

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='[Input Sheet.xlsm]Input Sheet'!R" & vTot & "C1"
    If Range("A4").Value <> 0 Then
    Do

    filepath = vDestPath & Range("a4") & ".Xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (filepath)
    vTot = vTot + 1

Next

Else
  ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "Do" keyword and you might want to end the If statement before the "Next" keyword. Something like this:

```
For vtot = 6 To 1000

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='[Input Sheet.xlsm]Input Sheet'!R" & vtot & "C1"
 If Range("A4").Value <> 0 Then

    filepath = vDestPath & Range("a4") & ".Xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (filepath)
    vtot = vtot + 1

 Else
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

 End If

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to improve your loops and queries. Half of the query `If` .. `Then` .. `Else` is within a `For`.. `Next` - not a good idea. Please check the position of `Next` and move to another place for your needs.

And there is an aborted `Do` missing some pseudo code like:

```
Dim k As Long

Do While k <= 10
   Cells(k, 1).Value = k
Loop
```

Remove `Do` and debug your code.